# Query services remotely using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to get status of services on remote server (Windows 2008 R2). I am using domain account. My problem is that instead of 150+ services, I am getting only 34.
Here is my code:

```
        var connection = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Username = $"{domain}\\{userName}",
            Password = password,
        };

        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\{ip}\root\cimv2", connection);
        var query = new ObjectQuery(importConfig.Query);
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
        var result = searcher.Get()
```

When I add my domain account do Administrators on this server, I am getting valid response - 150+ services.

I also tried to set (I tried AU, SID and many other combinations):

```
sc sdset SCMANAGER D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)
```

but the result is the same - 34 services are returned when domain account is not in Admins. Any idea why I don't see other services?

Comment: What happens if you run that query using WMIExplorer?(https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases)

Comment: @NicoRiff I am getting "The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)" error.